# Journey Builder - based on 2 DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have 2 DE: Contacts and quotes.

The scenario is:
Costumer asked for a price quote from a call center representative.
The representative fill in the quote in the CRM, and we want to send the quote to the costumer via SMS in a journey. (every time a new quote will be added to the DE, The journey will send the quote's contact SMS).

We have the contacts DE with the costumer mobile number and quotes DE with the quote details.

How do I build a journey that will sent the SMS? what is the entry event AUDIENCE? (contacts or quotes DE?). Which filter to choose?
You can see in the screen shots the connections between the 2 DE.
Thanks!!

[image]

[image]